# Why multiple references in same reference item in csproj file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In my work I saw a .csproj file has a reference item like below:

```
<Reference>
 <Reference Include="AssemblyA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
 <Reference Include="AssemblyB, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\xxx\yyy\AssemblyB.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
```

What does that mean? The HintPath of the first assembly is not listed, does that mean it should be the same folder of the second assembly? But why the .csproj file doesn't use that grammar for other references?

And also I noticed that for some references, though their `<Private>` property in the csproj file is False, the VS GUI still show copy local = true. I don't see a .USER file for that project, so how that could happen? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two references are entirely unconnected. The first one was probably referenced from the project folder, so: no need for a hint path because it will resolve automatically. It could also be in the GAC? B is clearly from somewhere entirely unrelated on disk - hence the need for a hint path.

Comment: Thanks Marc! But why they are all under the same <Reference> and </Reference> block? which made them seem related...

Comment: @SimonWang they aren't. Look again at the [image you posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzUaY.png). The "block" above is an **end** element. You have incorrectly edited it into a **start** element a minute ago. References are not nested.

Comment: The parent tag contains all references, and it's not "Reference" but `ItemGroup`, and the reference to AssemblyA ends in that line, HintPath is contained inside AssemblyB's reference tag, and is totally separate from AssemblyA's.

Comment: Oh Yeah! I got it. they are 2 separate "blocks", I overlooked the "/" at the end of the AssemblyA line. Sorry for that! Thank you guys! And do you know why the "private = false" but IDE still shows copy local = true?